# Angular 5 Pass data on click event from parent component to child component on button clicked at parent component

Tags: angular5, angular-event-emitter

i have some data bind in table and on click of any specific  i want to show current clicked object more related data in to another component(child component)

for example the data I'm taking from this link:
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

HTML Code:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>
      Id
    </th>
    <th>
      name
    </th>
    <th>
      username
    </th>
    <th>
      email
    </th>
    <th>
      street
    </th>
    <th>
      suite
    </th>
    <th>
      zipcode
    </th>
    <th>
      phone
    </th>
    <th>
      website
    </th>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of httpdata"> 
      <td>{{data.id}}
      </td> 
      <td>{{data.name}}
      </td> 
      <td>{{data.username}}
      </td> 
      <td>{{data.email}}
      </td> 
      <td>{{data.address.street}}
      </td> 
      <td>{{data.address.city}}
      </td> 
      <td>{{data.address.suite}}
      </td> 
      <td>{{data.address.zipcode}}
      </td> 
      <td>{{data.phone}}
      </td> 
      <td>{{data.website}}
      </td> 
      <td>
        <a routerLink="/conflict-details/conflict" (click)="onSelect(data)">Go to 
        </a> 
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

if you see there is one go to button i have in table when i click on any specific data it should show me complete info about current clicked 
but in my case i want to bind the data in another component when i click on go to for specific  that all td data should be display in new component(child).

simple i want to track click event for selected data in child component . and the table is rendered in parent component.

[image: if you can see in this screenshot i can bind the data in same component ,]

attached is the data table I have.

[image: the table where i have bind the data]

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz example?

Comment: As I understand, on click on particular Item you want to display that user's date in another component, right?

Comment: Yeah right, for example on my first component i'm going to show only two columns  like name and username. and rest of the things i want to display in another component when user will click on any specific <td> or go to button

Comment: Need HTML code to work with, can you post it in the question?

Comment: sure will do :) thanks in advance

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let data of httpdata">
                <td>{{data.id}}</td> <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.username}}</td> <td>{{data.email}}</td>
                <td>{{data.address.street}}</td>
                <td>{{data.address.city}}</td>
                <td>{{data.address.suite}}</td>
                <td>{{data.address.zipcode}}</td>
                <td>{{data.phone}}</td>
                <td>{{data.website}}</td>
                <td><a routerLink="/conflict-details/conflict" (click)="onSelect(data)">Go to </a> </td>
            </tr>

Comment: <div *ngIf="selectedUser" class="showdetails">
        <p><span>User:</span>{{selectedUser.id }}</p>
        <p><span>Name:</span> {{selectedUser.name}} </p>
        <p><span>Email: </span>{{selectedUser.email}} </p>
        <p><span>Phone: </span>{{selectedUser.phone}} </p>
        <p><span>Website: </span>{{selectedUser.website}} </p>
    </div>

Comment: sorry i don't see question edit option so posting it here only :(

Comment: export class ConflictComponent implements OnInit {

 private httpdata: any;
  public selectedUser = this.httpdata;


  constructor(public myserviceservice: MyserviceService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.myserviceservice.getUsers().subscribe(data => { this.httpdata = data ; },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('done loading users')
    );
  }


  onSelect(data): void {
    this.selectedUser = data;
  }

 .TS  - parent

Comment: Is it ok if your child component opened as Dialog Box?

Comment: No, it should be open in second component component and second component will have one back button to get back to the table component

Comment: I have the solution without another component! that means, Without child component!

Comment: Please tell . But make sure I don’t have to render current clicked object in same component. I want to show it separately because there are lot of information I have to show that’s why I’m taking it on separate component

Comment: Have added an answer with description!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`@Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) and [`@Output`](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) decorator to achieve the required output:

Changes:

***In parent Component:***

HTML Code:

```
<div>
  <table *ngIf="isVisible === true">
    <tr>
      <th>
        Id
      </th>
      <th>
        name
      </th>
      <th>
        username
      </th>
      <th>
        email
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of userInformation">
      <td>{{data.id}}
      </td>
      <td>{{data.name}}
      </td>
      <td>{{data.username}}
      </td>
      <td>{{data.email}}
      </td>
      <td>
        <a (click)="onSelect(data)">Go to
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div *ngIf="isVisible === false">
    <app-test-child [userInfo]="clickedUser" (notify)="backToList($event)"></app-test-child>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS Code:

Local variables:

```
userInformation: any;
isVisible : boolean = true;
clickedUser: any;
```

Two functions in the parent component:

```
onSelect(data)
{
   this.isVisible = false;
   this.clickedUser = data;
}

backToList(flag) {
  this.isVisible = flag;
  console.log(flag)
}
```

***In Child Component:***

HTML code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Id
    </th>
    <th>
      name
    </th>
    <th>
      username
    </th>
    <th>
      email
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{clickedUser.id}}
    </td>
    <td>{{clickedUser.name}}
    </td>
    <td>{{clickedUser.username}}
    </td>
    <td>{{clickedUser.email}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <a (click)="backToList()">Back
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';


@Input() userInfo: any;
@Output() notify: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

clickedUser: any;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.clickedUser = this.userInfo;
}

backToList() {
  var flag = true;
  this.notify.emit(flag);
}
```

Comment: thanks @prashant-pimpale, seems useful solution , let me try this way

Comment: Yeah @prashant it's it works for me with some small modification!!!!!! Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello @Prashant Pimpale, my requirement is almost same as like this question, 
as i need to get Id from my parent component to child component on when i click on the button of parent component. 
But i am getting this error `Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'editId' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.` 
Can you pls help ? stackblitz.com/edit/angular-duduth

Comment: @aananddham have you posted question for this?

Comment: @aananddham need explanation, do you id of that button to available in the parent?

Comment: Yes it is available in the parent component. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-duduth
Pls review a comment that i have mentioned on the buttonclick event `editDetails()`

Comment: @aananddham You can't!  to work above code you have to use `<child-app [editId]="your_id"></child-app>` for you must have to read documentation

Comment: Perfect... can you pls provide me a exact link so that i can get better explanation of documentation. ?

Comment: @aananddham yes I will, but I am afraid, about your requirement

Comment: @aananddham I will request you to open a new question with Expected behaviour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210160/discussion-between-aananddham-and-prashant-pimpale).

Answer (score 2):

try this

In HTML
update

```
<a routerLink="/conflict-details/conflict" (click)="onSelect(data)">Go to 
        </a>
```

to

```
<a (click)="onSelect(data)">Go to 
            </a>
```

In Parent Component

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private router: Router) {
   }
   onSelect(data) {
      this.router.config.find(r => r.component == ChildComponent).data = data;
      this.router.navigate(["/conflict-details/conflict"]);
   }
}
```

In Child Component

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
   SentItem : any;
   constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) { }
   ngOnInit() {
      this.router.data.subscribe(r=>this.SentItem =r);
  }
}
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined`