# Angular 7 - Search bar and results in different views

Tags: angular, rest, search

I have created two components :

- `search-bar.component.ts` : displayed in all the views
- `search.component.ts` : should display the results (response from a REST API)

The working is like this : wherever in the application, I want to perform a global search (products, users, events, etc...). I write something in the search bar, click on SEARCH, and I am redirected to the results page. The results are fetched from a REST API.

PS : I have been searching for hours on the Internet and I did not found.. strange ! I have been reading a lot about `@Input` and `@Output` indeed.

I am close to achieve what I want, with this kind of code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-bar',
  templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.css']
})
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(search: string, from: string, to: string) {
    this.router.navigate(['recherche'], {
      queryParams: {
        search: search,
        from: from,
        to: to
      }
    });
  }

}
```

The form is built like this : `<form ngNoForm class="form-inline">` and the magic `(click)="onSubmit(search.value, from.value, to.value);"`.

But I do not think that this is the best way to do this kind of stuff. (this is my **first problem**)

Moreover, when I am on the results view, if I do a search again on the search-bar, it reloads completely the application like if it was a basic `href`. (this is my **second problem**)

I do not find much use cases or example for this needs I have, but it seems to be quite basic.

**EDIT 1 : code of both components**

Code of the `search-bar.component.html` :

```
<div class="event-background-blue margin-20-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Search -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <form ngNoForm class="form-inline">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <input #search id="search" name="search" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="col">
              <div class="input-group date datepicker" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-week-start="1" data-date-language="fr">
                <input placeholder="Du" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" #from name="from" autocomplete="off" >
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
              <div class="input-group date datepicker" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-week-start="1" data-date-language="fr">
                <input placeholder="Au" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" #to name="to" autocomplete="off" >
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
              <button (click)="onSubmit(search.value, from.value, to.value);" class="btn btn-black" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code of `search.component.html` :

```
<app-search-bar></app-search-bar>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1 class="title-search text-primary">Search</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Count of Events -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 margin-20-bottom">
      <h3>Events</h3>
    </div>

    <app-event class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-10" *ngFor="let event of events" [event]="event"></app-event>

    <div class="col-12" *ngIf="!events">
      <p>No event, go to <a routerLink="/evenements">events !</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2 : adding code of search.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { EventService } from '../../../services/event.service';
import { Event, EventsResp, EventsSearch } from '../../../models/event';
import { LocationService } from '../../../services/location.service';
import { Location, LocationsResp, LocationsSearch } from '../../../models/location';

import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private eventService: EventService,
    private locationService: LocationService,
  ) { }

  perPage: number = 20;
  page: number = 1;
  error: Error;

  locations: Location[];
  events: Event[];

  ngOnInit() {
    // Retreive the parameters
    const search = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('search');
    const from = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('from');
    const to = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('to');

    this.listEvents(search, from, to);
    this.listLocations(search, from, to);
  }

  // listEvents returns all the events
  listEvents(search, from, to): void {
    // Set the parameters
    let parameters: EventsSearch = {
      from: moment(from).toISOString(),
      to: moment(to).toISOString(),
      search: search,
      page: this.page,
      per_page: this.perPage,
      sort: "",
      _location_id: ""
    };

    // List the events
    this.eventService.listEvents(parameters)
      .subscribe((resp: EventsResp) => {
        this.events = resp['events'];
      });
  }

  // listLocations returns all the locations
  listLocations(search, from, to): void {
    // Set the parameters
    let parameters: LocationsSearch = {
      page: this.page,
      is_city_guide: undefined,
      per_page: this.perPage,
      sort: "",
      search: search
    };

    // List the locations
    this.locationService.listLocations(parameters)
      .subscribe((resp: LocationsResp) => {
        this.locations = resp['locations'];
      });
  }
}
```

**EDIT 3 : As an example, the search bar in Google Drive is a perfect example, it is displayed everywhere, and the results are displayed in the results page.**

**EDIT 4** :

I took a strong look at this : [Passing @Input and subscribing to @Output while navigating to a Route in Angular 2 Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558497/passing-input-and-subscribing-to-output-while-navigating-to-a-route-in-angular)

and this :
[Angular 5 Pass data on click event from parent component to child component on button clicked at parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53703582/angular-5-pass-data-on-click-event-from-parent-component-to-child-component-on-b)

Comment: Can you add the current HTML code of both components?

Comment: Please share html file

Comment: Ok let me edit the question

Comment: I added the requested two codes

Comment: @Elwyn can you try to add your code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: @davecar21 : I am sorry but I never used it before, do you really need it ? Thanks a lot

Comment: I added more code

Comment: I added a description of an example that shows what I want to achieve : the search bar of Google Drive

Answer (score 8):

You have two ways to perform this:

**The quick and event based**

Create an event emitter in your search-bar component, and trigger it in the onSubmit function, passing the search value.

```js
// Search Bar Component

import { EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-bar',
  templateUrl: ['./search-bar.component.html'],
  styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.scss']
})
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {

@Output() searchEvent = new EventEmitter();

// constructor

  onSubmit(searchValue: string, ...) {
    // your function

    this.searchEvent.emit(searchValue);
  }

}
```

```html
<!-- Search Component -->

<app-search-bar (searchEvent)="fetchResults($event)">
</app-search-bar>
```

**The service based way**

Create a search service provided in your parent module, and import it both components.
In the service, create a search function that will perform the Http request and update a subject. The search bar component will call this function on submit. Then create an observable and listen to it from the search component in order to fetch results.

```js
// Your service

searchResults = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Result>>();

// constructor


onResults() {
  return this.searchResults.asObservable();
}

search(value: string) {
  this.http.post(url, value).subscribe(results => this.searchResults.next(results);
}




// Search-Bar component

onSubmit(value: string) {
  // code
  this.searchService.search(value);
}


// Search component

ngOnInit() {
  this.searchService.onResults().subscribe(results => this.results = results));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this complete answer, I suppose that the "service based" in the cleanest one ?

Comment: It would be a bit better and more scalable in your case. If you want to use the results elsewhere later for instance, that's the solution to go for :)

Comment: I already use a service for the searching, you can see it in the code I added in the question, may I ask if it matches your code ? Moreover, just to be sure, the `BehaviorSubject` is just an example right ? I my case it will be `Event[]`

Comment: I added the code of my search component as you can see I already use a service

Comment: The behaviorSubject is a container that allows you to create an Observable from, and react to data updates. You can set a BehaviorSubject<Event[]> in your case

Comment: Did you see the code I added showing that I use a service ? it is exactly what you propose. That being said, I still having the reloading issue :(

Comment: Is your listEvent method based on a Subject ? If not then it might explain the reloading issue. Using a separate method for the request and a subject as observable to handle the data should prevent this

Comment: Actually, it is not a `Subject` as I did not event know what it is. Moreover, one thing that differs from what I did is that I do not see anywhere a "routerLink", is it normal ?

Comment: The route parsing part is currently handled by your component, and wasn't really part of the question as I understood :) . Consider the search service in my example as a generic implementation that you can apply to both your locationService and eventService

Comment: Yes but I need to use `router.navigate`, so I do not know how to use your solution with the navigation..

Answer (score 0):

Just need to use @input and @output for this kind of situation 
here just need to use @output and pass data from parent component

Comment: But the results are in a different view, like the Google Drive search box you see ? So  I also need to use `navigate` I guess ?

Comment: Let me add this example : I am in the `PRODUCTS LIST` view, I make a search in the search box, I am redirected to the results view which is NOT the same view as the PRODUCTS LIST with filter, it is a separate view, because I search for products, but also users, events, etc... you see ?